# Search key in json object based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I populate the options of a select input field based on json data I get from a php-script.

This works fine, but I want to show some extra info, *based on the selected option*.
Basically, I'm looking for a way to find the key that goes with the selected option:

```
 $("#code").html(result[whichkey]["uniquecode"]);
```

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv8Lm1uj/2/) hopefully makes my question a bit more clearer.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `option` element is created with the `uniquecode` of the object as its value, why do you even need to access the object again? You can just retrieve the `value` property of the selected `option`...?

Assuming this is just because you've oversimplified your example, and the objects within the array do hold other useful data which is not held in the `option` element itself, then you can use `$.grep` to filter the array of objects by the selected `uniquecode`, like this:

```js
var json = '[{"uniquecode":"b32dez2","name":"John Doe","foo":"bar"},{"uniquecode":"a2df32","name":"Adam Smith","foo":"buzz"}]';
var result = JSON.parse(json);
var $sel = $('#names').change(function() {
  var value = this.value;
  var obj = $.grep(result, function(e) {
    return e.uniquecode == value;
  });
  $("#code").html(obj[0].uniquecode + ' / ' + obj[0].foo)
});;

result.forEach(function(obj) {
  $('<option value="' + obj.uniquecode + '">' + obj.name + '</option>').appendTo($sel)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="names"></select>
<div id="code"></div>
```

Note that I added the `foo` property to the object to show you how to access properties of the object outside of those placed directly on the `option` element.

Also note that I simplified the code that generates the `option` elements as well. If you're going to use jQuery once in your project, you may as well use it everywhere.

Comment: I indeed oversimplified my question, the objects within the array hold other useful data which is not held in the option element itself. Your example does exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know about `$.grep`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just stumbled upon a new problem. I use jQuery Validation (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) to validate the form. With this plugin, I can define certain rules: `rules: {'name-of-input-field': {required: true, range: [60, 120]}`. This will only allow digits between 60 and 120. How could I change this range dynamically, based on the selected option, if `range_upperlimit` and `range_lowerlimit` is also part of the json object?

Comment: I believe the validator will also respect attributes you add to the element to set it's rules. Check the documentation for more info, or feel free to start a new question for it

Comment: Should have checked to docs first. Thanks for pointing me in that direction: turned out I only had to use `$( "#id-of-input-field" ).rules( "add",...` to dynamically add new rules to a field. Problem solved!